# Retrieve POST items with different names

Tags: php, post

I'm passing some values with POST to another file.
One (or more) of those values are:
Equip1, Equip2, Equip3, ..., EquipN

I'm able to know how many EquipN I have, but not know how to get their values.
I thought this works, but it's not:

```
for ($Equip_aux=1; $Equip_aux<=$Number_of_Equip; $Equip_aux++) {
    $aux = "'Equipamento".$Equip."'";
    $VALUE = $_POST[$aux];
}
```

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm able to know how many EquipN I have, but not know how to get their values.

Here's the corrected version of your for loop:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $Number_of_Equip; $i++) {
    $aux = "Equip$i"; 
    $VALUE = $_POST[$aux];
}
```

Notice that you can also loop trough the post values with `foreach`:

```
foreach ($_POST as $p) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that... Nice! VERY NIVE! Thank you once more.